# Ubuntu 12.04 - Phpmyadmin - 403 forbidden

Tags: apache, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-12.04

***Background***

I am running Ubuntu 12.04, and when i go to my url http://domain_name.com/phpmyadmin/ i am getting the error:

*You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/ on this server.*

I have used a symlink for phpmyadmin which points to

> "usr/share/phpmyadmin"

it has permission 777.

***Question***

why is it showing as permission denied?

Thanks

Aiden

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons Apache does not allow 777 permission.

You can use a hard link (ln) other than a soft link (ln -s).

Or

Download the PhpMyAdmin tarball from the site and decompress it in '`/var/www/`' directory as root. Then rename the directory to phpmyadmin(or something you need).

Then try to view it via a web browser '`http://localhost/phpmyadmin/`'. In the initial stage you will see a wizard to setup PhpMyAdmin. (Sometimes you may need to change the permissions on '`config.inc.php`', for that just follow the instructions on the wizard.)